# How to get row data by clicking a button in a row in an ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a `GridView` in a ASP.NET web application, in which I have added two buttons in each row:

```html
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Now how I can get the row data from gridview simply by clicking an edit button in a row?

Answer (score 52):

You can also use button click event like this:

```html
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                    OnClick="MyButtonClick" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```cs
protected void MyButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the button that raised the event
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    //Get the row that contains this button
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

#### OR

You can do like this to get data:

```cs
 void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {

    // If multiple ButtonField column fields are used, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Select")
    {
      // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      // property to an Integer.
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    

      // Get the last name of the selected author from the appropriate
      // cell in the GridView control.
      GridViewRow selectedRow = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];
    }
}
```

and Button in gridview should have command like this and handle rowcommand event:

```html
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        onrowcommand="CustomersGridView_RowCommand"
        runat="server">

        <columns>
          <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
            commandname="Select"
            headertext="Select Customer" 
            text="Select"/>
        </columns>
  </asp:gridview>
```

[**Check full example on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx)

Comment: thnx again for quick reply.I hv tried that...its showing ithis error "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Comment: @TamalKantiDey - hey just set EnableEventValidation="false"  will remove that error

Comment: where I have to set this EnableEventValidation attribute? In grid I cant find any attribute like this.

Comment: in page at the top in this tag " <%@ Page "

Comment: thnx its working,I mean no error is comming. but that _RowCommand event is not firing.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey - have added that event on gridview as i did in mark up ..it yes that it must fire

Comment: @TamalKantiDey,you should bind gridview at first time page load only

Comment: @PranayRana : Sorry to say, I did it as u wrote...but still not firing.

Comment: this was answered 5 years ago but still helpful. I never really knew about the .NamingContainer property. thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Place the `commandName` in .aspx page

```
 <asp:Button  ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="CoolButtons" CommandName="DeleteData"/>
```

Subscribe the `rowCommand` event for the grid  and you can try like this,

```
protected void grdBillingdata_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteData")
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            HiddenField hdnDataId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnDataId");
         }
}
```

Comment: This isn't bad except you forgot to include where `hdnDataId` came from.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            OnClick="MyButtonClick" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and your method

```
 protected void MyButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //Get the button that raised the event
Button btn = (Button)sender;

    //Get the row that contains this button
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same like in Pranay Rana's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you would want your buttons in an item template.You can alternatively do it the following way , there by giving you the full power of the grid row editing event.You are also given a bonus of wiring easily the cancel and delete functionality.

**Mark up**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="EditImageButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"
    ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png" Style="height: 16px" ToolTip="Edit" 
    CausesValidation="False"  />

      </ItemTemplate>

         <EditItemTemplate>

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                        Text="Update"  Visible="true" ImageUrl="~/images/saveHS.png" 
                        />
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"   
                        ImageUrl="~/images/Edit_UndoHS.png"  />

                 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"   
                        ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"  />

             </EditItemTemplate>


        <ControlStyle BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" />
               <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code behind**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

TextBox txtledName =   (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtAccountName");

 //then do something with the retrieved textbox's text.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LnKB" Text='edit' OnClick="LnKB_Click"   > 
 </asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

  protected void LnKB_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
        LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;

        GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int x = clickedRow.RowIndex;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(yourgridviewname.Rows[x].Cells[0].Text);
        lbl.Text = yourgridviewname.Rows[x].Cells[2].Text; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <asp:Button  ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server"  OnClick="btnEdit_Click" CssClass="CoolButtons"/>


protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Button btnEdit = (Button)sender;
       GridViewRow Grow = (GridViewRow)btnEdit.NamingContainer;
      TextBox txtledName = (TextBox)Grow.FindControl("txtAccountName");
      HyperLink HplnkDr = (HyperLink)Grow.FindControl("HplnkDr");
      TextBox txtnarration = (TextBox)Grow.FindControl("txtnarration");
     //Get the gridview Row Details
}
```

And Same As for Delete button

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnS10_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in Grd.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk_Single = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChkSendOne");
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string id = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("lblSNo") as Label).Text;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(id) <= 10)
                {
                   
                    chk_Single.Checked = true;
                    if (chk_Single.Checked == true)
                    {
                        lblSelectedRecord.InnerText = (Convert.ToInt32(lblSelectedRecord.InnerText) + 1).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```