# Retrieving a single value from a list to use in a calculation

Tags: c#, list, uwp

I'm a bit confused here. I hard coded my list but I want to pull one specific value from every item in the list (The Price or iPrice value). So that when in the xaml when the button is clicked it adds to the total pricing of everything.

Button is Clicked Total Price needs to increase.I'm not sure if i'm researching with the wrong terminology this seem's like something that should be somewhat simplistic.

I Tried checking the Price parameter and if the value corresponds to a set value like 10 then just add 10 to the pricing, This dint work but even if it did it doesn't feel right

```cs
<GridView Name="mylist" ItemsSource="{x:Bind itemlist}" Margin="0,91,0,0">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Add" Click="CheckTotal_Click" ></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
   int Pricing = Model.TotalSpent;
List<Item> itemlist = new List<Item>();
public void Items()
{          
    itemlist.Add(new Item("Coke", "A Fizzy Soft Drink", 15));
    itemlist.Add(new Item("Burger", "A Mouth Watering Mouthfull", 25));
    itemlist.Add(new Item("Chips", "Crunchy Crispy Goodness!", 10));
    itemlist.Add(new Item("Bilton", "Yum Yum", 50));
    itemlist.Add(new Item("Caps", "Show of how much you love us", 80));
}
  void CheckTotal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {

            txtTotal.Text = "Total: " + Pricing ;
        }
```

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    private string iName;
    private string iDescription;
    private int iPrice;

    public Item(string iName, string iDescription, int iPrice)
    {
        this.iName = iName;
        this.iDescription = iDescription;
        this.iPrice = iPrice;
    }

    public string ItemName
    { 
        get { return iName; }
        set { iName = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return iDescription; }
        set { iDescription = value; }
    }
    public int Price
    {
        get { return iPrice; }
        set { iPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

Front end result is the following:

Coke

A Fizzy Soft Drink

Price is 15

(Button)

Comment: Could you show the code for the `CheckTotal_Click` method? And I'm assuming that you're keeping a "total price" somewhere, appending the price of each item clicked. If so, could you show that code as well?

Comment: Edited for you, Not much to add there as of yet as that is the method in question. I'm using the "Pricing" Variable to append within that page and the Price model to append globally as I plan on saving this a SQL DB in a bit

Comment: You could do something like this: `int total = itemlist.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(iPrice));`

Comment: Wouldn't I be just parsing every "Price Value" into a total. I'd have to treat this as a "Store" so what you click is what adds What I could do is a really scruffy way of doing it but add buttons outside of the generated stacks and add like that but if i ever add more "Items" its a mess

Comment: @RoyAurele Assuming that CheckTotal_Click is clicked only when you want to know the total from the list? Is that the case? And you could just display one button outside your list and then just find the total sum of all the current existing items.

Comment: Its not The Output I gave is created for every item in the list but the same function is called from every click as that's how its being generated essentially what I want is not a total of all of the pricing's in the list as I could just manually do that. I want to Take a price from any item on that list and just add that items price to the total so if I have coke and Caps for instance and I click caps it only adds Caps total not Coke and Caps if that makes sense?

Comment: @RoyAurele Makes sense, for that you would need to know which button was clicked and then get that row in your `_Click` method. Check this link out on how to get the current button clicked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254880/how-to-get-row-data-by-clicking-a-button-in-a-row-in-an-asp-net-gridview

Comment: I Found a Solution will be posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
 private void mylist_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedItem = (Item)e.ClickedItem;
            Pricing += clickedItem.Price;
            var collection = (ObservableCollection<Item>)mylist.ItemsSource;
            int index = collection.IndexOf(clickedItem);



            addtototal();
        }

        public int addtototal()
        {
            Model.TotalSpent = Pricing;
            txtTotal.Text = Pricing.ToString();
            return Pricing;

        }
```

I gave up on directly trying to access a clicked member in the list-view so my intention was to rather get the index of that "clicked item" and then set hard-coded "Price" values for every index so E.G if(index == 1) Pricing += 10;

Instead I utilized the event args to pull a value from the indexed "item".

I apologize if the explanation is horrid.