# Can't get the grid view data and store it to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<div class="container">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Medium">

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student ID">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"   Width="80px"  Text='<%#Eval("studentID") %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>


  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>                                     
                  <asp:LinkButton runat="server"  OnCommand="LinkButton_Click" Text=" VoteCandidate"> </asp:LinkButton>     
         </ItemTemplate>



 </asp:GridView>

    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my form to show the gridview.

```
protected void loadCandidate()
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select studentID from candidate where faculty='FOCS'", con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String MyConnection2 = "Server=localhost;database=ovs;Uid=root;password=; Convert Zero Datetime=True";
        foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
            
            String query = "insert into voting (studentID)values ('" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "')" ;
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(query, MyConn2);
         
          MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
          MyConn2.Open();
          MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
          MyConn2.Close();
        }

    }
```

When I execute the sql insert command, no error occur, but I expect the studentID that displayed in the gridview being stored in the voting table, but the studentID on the voting table are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a template field in your `GridView`, you can't use the cell directly, you need to look for the label inside the cell like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
{
    Label lblStudentId = (Label)g1.Cells[0].FindControl("lblID");
    string studentId = lblStudentId.Text;
    // now proceed with your inserting.
}
```

But if you using the loop the way you do it right now, there will be an insert for every row in the `GridView`, not only for the one you clicked on...
If you want to get the Id for the row the `LinkButton` is in, don't iterate over the rows. Instead use the `NamingContainer`-property of the sender like this:

```cs
LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
GridViewRow g1 = (GridViewRow)linkButton.NamingContainer;
Label lblStudentId = (Label)g1.Cells[0].FindControl("lblID");
string studentId = lblStudentId.Text;
// now proceed with your inserting.
```

For more details look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254880/how-to-get-row-data-by-clicking-a-button-in-a-row-in-an-asp-net-gridview)

Comment: Hello, can you give me some suggestion on how to insert the row I selected instead of every row in the grid view?

Comment: Updated answer - take a look